# How do I change the selector so that the website shows login instead of signup using selenium python and chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsL77.png)    

REGISTER


LOGIN


The code i wrote in python

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='sectionContainer']//div[@id='login_section_btn']")
#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','active_section_btn')", element)
```

Error message that i am getting is:

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@id='sectionContainer']//div[@id='login_section_btn']"}
> (

Comment: please cjheck if its inside iframe

Comment: no it's not inside an iframe

Comment: What happens if you add time.sleep(9) before find element

Comment: I'm gettting different errors
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.141)

Comment: Please mention the error

Comment: please add the screen shot of the website

Comment: if you can provide the url also

Comment: https://secura.e-sim.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://secura.e-sim.org/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, "// div[@id='sectionContainer']//div[@id='login_section_btn']"))
).click()
```

you should use explicit wait for waiting till the element is loaded properly. THe second error element not interactable may be bacause the button is disabled or something unless we have access to website or have screen shot its hard to tell.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/askvyas/Desktop/scrp/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    login("https://www.secura.e-sim.org", "registeredPlayerLogin", myFbEmail, "password", myFbPassword, "Submit")
  File "/Users/askvyas/Desktop/scrp/main.py", line 22, in login
    (By.XPATH, "//*[@data-box-name=\"//div[@id='sectionContainer']//div[@id='login_section_btn']\""))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Im getting this

Comment: @ASKVYAS add some extra characters updated the answer its wprking could you try it out